# Merge sort tree like structure

Tags: algorithm, mergesort

I have the following homework question:

> Sort the numbers  7   12    8    6    9    1    4    3    5    10   11    2
>   using merge sort. Illustrate the tree-like structure and the
>   partitions at each step. (10 points).

**I don't know if this is right. This is what I have worked out:**
[image]

At step 5 I where not sure what to do. I place a circle on the image. Is this procedure right? I believe this illustration is answering the question.

### EDIT

**Sorry I should have placed the circle one step before. I place the circle at step 6**

---

### Final EDIT

**Thanks to your answers I ended up with:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line where you have the arrow is wrong.  The left side of the tree, starting from the beginning, looks like this

```
{7,12,8,6,9,1}
{7,12,8} {6,9,1}
{7}, {12,8}, {6}, {9,1}
```

And now because all sets are of size 1 or 2, we sort and then merge:

```
{7}, {8,12}, {6}, {1,9}
{7,8,12} {1,6,9}
{1,6,7,8,9,12}
```

The right side is left as an exercise for the reader ;)

Comment: Well it's not an error if you perform one more step and only start merging if every set is of size 1. However, it's true that the merging part is wrong in the example.

Comment: Perlic thanks for the help. I placed a final edit on my question based on your solution. I guess that is what you meant right?

Comment: @Tono Nam: Usually you split until only groups of size `1` remain. At least that is the description of the algorithm that is found everywhere. In any case, your final diagram is missing one step, that of sorting the groups of 2 (which would not be an issue if you had splitted one more time). You can't merge two non-sorted groups like `7` and `12,8`.

Answer (score 2):

I think the tree from line 5 on should look like this:

```
7 | 12 | 8 | 6 | 9 | 1 | 4 | 3 | 5 | 10 | 11 | 2

7 |  8,12  | 6 |  1,9  | 4 |  3,5  | 10 | 2,11

  7,8,12   |   1,6,9   |   3,4,5   | 2,10,11

      1,6,7,8,9,12     |    2,3,4,5,10,11

          1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12
```

Why? Because you split the group `7,12,8` into `7` and `12,8` in line 3. Because of how recursion works, you will than have to merge `8,12` first before merging all three elements.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote some code which helps you work out part of your answer. It modifies the algorithm to store the depth and order each list is passed into mergesort.

You would need to adjust merge() so that it records the result returned by merge() also.

Note the two globals for tracking, and the depth paramenter are the only modifications.

```
# Retrieved from: http://en.literateprograms.org/Merge_sort_(Python)?oldid=16663

glob_lists=[]
glob_order=0

def merge(left, right):
    result = []
    i ,j = 0, 0
    while i < len(left) and j < len(right):
        if left[i] <= right[j]:
            result.append(left[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            result.append(right[j])
            j += 1

    result += left[i:]
    result += right[j:]
    return result

def mergesort(_list,depth):
    global glob_order
    global glob_lists
    glob_order+=1
    glob_lists.append((depth,glob_order,_list))
    if len(_list) < 2:
        return _list
    else:
        middle = len(_list) / 2
        left = mergesort(_list[:middle],depth+1)
        right = mergesort(_list[middle:],depth+1)
        return merge(left, right)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print mergesort([7,12,8,6,9,1,4,3,5,10,11,2],0)

glob_lists.sort()
print glob_lists

from itertools import groupby

for depth,g in groupby(glob_lists,key=lambda i:i[0]):
    g = [i[-1] for i in g]
    print depth," "*(10-len(g))," | ".join(map(str,g))

0           [7, 12, 8, 6, 9, 1, 4, 3, 5, 10, 11, 2]
1          [7, 12, 8, 6, 9, 1] | [4, 3, 5, 10, 11, 2]
2        [7, 12, 8] | [6, 9, 1] | [4, 3, 5] | [10, 11, 2]
3    [7] | [12, 8] | [6] | [9, 1] | [4] | [3, 5] | [10] | [11, 2]
4    [12] | [8] | [9] | [1] | [3] | [5] | [11] | [2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you finished the splitting and have single numbers, the highlighted row starts merging all numbers together again, but this time they'll be put back in order.
The middle row is also the row where the last recursion layer is reached.

Wikipedia, though you might checked that already out, has actually a pretty good explanation to it
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mergesort